# Using R code: Converting date in integer format 20081028

Tags: r

While converting integer value **20081028** to date format, I have written a code:

```
lakers<-as.Date(lakers$date, "%Y%m%d")
```

I am getting error to converting char to date.

Can you help me. Where I am doing wrong

Following are the details of the code error.

lakers$date<-as.Date(lakers$date,"%Y%m%d")

Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

while if I use R code :

lakers$Date = as.POSIXct.Date(lakers$Date, "%Y%m%d")

Then the following error I am getting.

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Date, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 34624

> 

Note down my sample data.

head(lakers)

```
date opponent game_type  time period     etype team    player result points
```

1 20081028    POR    home    12:00   1      jump ball    OFF           0
2 20081028   POR      home 11:39      1      shot  LAL           Pau Gasol

Please help me.

Comment: Can you paste your error please, also put a sample of your data , use `mydata <- head(Lakers,10)` and use `dput(mydata)` , paste the entire output of last command here

Answer (score 1):

It needs it be in a standard date format first. Try:

```
Lakers$Date = as.POSIXct.Date(Lakers$Date, "%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It will convert the integer to Year-Month-Day format. But first install lubridate package.

```
lakers$date <- ymd(lakers1$date)
```